# Toggle not working on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried all sorts, using answers from stackoverflow and others, its becoming very frustrating because it should work. Am trying to make a label change colour when clicked on to select the checkbox. Below are my codes;

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("color_change");
});
})
```

```css
.style_check {
  padding: 20px;
  background: yellow;
}
.color_change {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="style_check">
  <input type="checkbox" name="roles" value="1" />
  <span class="p_check">Block User</span>
</label>
```

What exactly can I do to make it work?

Comment: Add you relevant HTML code please.

Comment: I have, it was a mistake at first.

Comment: Why do you have the mysql tag on this question?

Comment: The `})`was already there before the edits. So I guess that is the problem.

Comment: that was my mistake i had jquery function opened on top initially, but after running the correct thing, it still doesn't work. Is it that there is another javascript somewhere that is affecting my codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your posted code - I just removed `})` and your example works.

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("color_change");
});
```

```css
.style_check {
  padding: 20px;
  background: yellow;
}
.color_change {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="style_check">
  <input type="checkbox" name="roles" value="1" />
  <span class="p_check">Block User</span>
</label>
```

Comment: I know it works, but it doesn't work on the file am using, perhaps some other JavaScript is preventing it.

Comment: Yeah am correct, i moved my code to the footer and it worked, based on precedence, some other codes using same callup was preventing it somehow and i can't be checking that now, because i have over 10 javacript libs embeded to my page. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Should work if you remove the extra `})` and if you've the correct HTML with correct relation between `checkbox`'s and `label`'s, check the sample below.

Hope this helps.

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("color_change");
});
```

```css
.color_change{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" /> 
  <label>Checkbox 1</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" /> 
  <label>Checkbox 1</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" /> 
  <label>Checkbox 1</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" /> 
  <label>Checkbox 1</label>
</div>
```

**Your case snippet :**

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("color_change");
});
```

```css
.style_check {padding:20px; background:yellow;}
.color_change {background:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="style_check">
  <input type="checkbox" name="roles" value="1"  />
  <span class="p_check">Block User</span>
</label>

<label class="style_check">
  <input type="checkbox" name="roles" value="1"  />
  <span class="p_check">Block User</span>
</label>

<label class="style_check">
  <input type="checkbox" name="roles" value="1"  />
  <span class="p_check">Block User</span>
</label>

<label class="style_check">
  <input type="checkbox" name="roles" value="1"  />
  <span class="p_check">Block User</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some extra `})` at your javascript. So might be syntax issues. I have set up working example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lapkritinis/2oayLyfs/):

HTML:

```
<form >
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" > I have a bike<br>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("color_change");
});
```

CSS:

```
.color_change {
  color: red;
}
```